# Merge the Column

Tags: python, pandas

I given the sample of data-frame

```
  Name value  A   Msg_A       Invalid_A     Msg_B   Invalid_B       Msg_C        Invalid_C 

0  j    3     A  Not VAid XYZ   True        VAlid       False     Not Valid_c     True   
1  B    4     B  VAid ABC       False       notVAlidb   TRue      Not Valid_c     True
```

i want df like this

```
   Name value A    Msg_A      Invalid_A   Msg_B    Invalid_B       Msg_C     Invalid_C  Message                Invalid_main

0  J     3    A  Not VAid XYZ   True     VAlid       False     Not Valid_c     True  Not VAid XYZ,Not Valid_c   True
1  B     4    B  VAid ABC      False     notVAlidb   TRue      Not Valid_c     True   notVAlidb,Not Valid_c     True
```

i want to merge the msg_ in message column in if invalid column contains `True`

shape : `print(df.filter(like='Invalid_').values[:,None].shape)` --> (4, 1, 8)
i try with

```
# Final merge of All the Valididation and concat Message 
df1 = df.filter(like='Status_')
df2 = df.filter(like='Invalid_')
#set columnsnames
df2.columns = df1.columns

# Final Df with All the Validation
df['message'] = df1.where(df2).apply(lambda x:','.join(x.dropna()),1)
```

i want to merge the Invalid_ all  column into one cloumn if any one Invalid_ containes True then set the True value in Invalid_main column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter to get `invalids` and `messages` as two dataframes, and then perform an element-wise product to choose the messages that are invalid; then join them with `","` after dropping empty strings. For the `Invalid Main`, we take `any` of `invalids`:

```
invalids = df.filter(like="Invalid")
messages = df.filter(like="Msg")

df["Message"] = (invalids.values * messages).agg(lambda s: ",".join(s[s!=""]), axis=1)

df["Invalid_main"] = invalids.any(axis=1)
```

to get

```
>>> df

  Name     value A         Msg_A  Invalid_A      Msg_B  Invalid_B        Msg_C  Invalid_C                   Message  Invalid_main
0 j           3  A  Not VAid XYZ       True      VAlid      False  Not Valid_c       True  Not VAid XYZ,Not Valid_c          True
1 B           4  B      VAid ABC      False  notVAlidb       True  Not Valid_c       True     notVAlidb,Not Valid_c          True
```

Comment: Good use of element-wise product!  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Message'] = df.apply(lambda x: [y for y, z in zip(x[3::2], x[4::2]) if z], axis=1).str.join(',')
df['Invalid_main'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[4::2].any(), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  Name  value  A         Msg_A  Invalid_A      Msg_B  Invalid_B        Msg_C  Invalid_C                   Message  Invalid_main
0    j      3  A  Not VAid XYZ       True      VAlid      False  Not Valid_c       True  Not VAid XYZ,Not Valid_c          True
1    B      4  B      VAid ABC      False  notVAlidb       True  Not Valid_c       True     notVAlidb,Not Valid_c          True
```

Comment: i want a new column , "Invalid_main" if any invalid_ column contains True then set True

Comment: @user14784453  See my edit, now including it as well

Comment: it's sample data i have total 104 column and not in order

Comment: @user14784453  This should work well as long as the columns starts at the 4th column and the Msg_* and Invalid_* goes in pairs.

Comment: @user14784453 You mean  `Invalid_A` could be not immediately following ``Msg_A` , right ?   How about their relative sequence ?   Would `Invalid_B` goes before `Invalid_A` in column sequence ?

Comment: you can try with filter(invalid_)